# I am passing URL with & to my C# API Controller. However I only receive half of the URL upto & and anything after the & character is trimmed?

Tags: c#, download, blob, urlencode

I am passing this web URL **(http://localhost:4200/downloadDocuments/Ruzzy&Fuzzy.zip)** to my download controller in Angular which further calls my API download controller.

My API controller looks something like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDocumentFromFileStorage")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetDocumentFromFileStorage(string documentName)
{
    try
    {
        return await new TaskFactory().StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = _documentDownloadService.GetDocumentFromFileStorage(documentName.ToString());
                return response;
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log4NetErrorLogger(ex);

        return CreateHttpResponseMessage();
    }
}
```

However the URL I receive in the controller is always **http://localhost:4200/downloadDocuments/Ruzzy** it trims everything after the & character causing the download to fail.

Please explain why this happens, I've tried to encode it with `%26` and `&amp;` but with no luck so far as it gives me an incomplete URL always.

Comment: why're you sending `&`? why not send like `ruzzy\?documentName=fuzzy.zip`?

Comment: Well the user first uploads the document with the document name Ruzzy&Fuzzy.xlsx and after processing I store the document in Azure File storage within a zip folder with the same name as that of the file within it. Ruzzy& Fuzzy.zip is the complete name of the file.

Comment: Why doesn't your Route info match the example URL you're giving (GetDocumentFromFileStorage vs downloadDocuments)?

Comment: @HansKilian downloadDocuments is my angular component where I do some processing and from there I pass the Ruzzy&Fuzzy filename further ahead to the service which calls my API get method GetDocumentFromFileStorage

Comment: Please isolate your issue to the C# bit then. What does the request passed to C# look like?

Comment: Use something like your browsers Developer Tools / Fiddler to look at the request that's going from the browser **to** the server. I *suspect* that the URL is intended to look something like this: `https://server-name:port/GetDocumentFromFileStorage?documentName=http://localhost:4200/downloadDocuments/Ruzzy&Fuzzy.zip` but that's not what's getting there - this is likely because `documentName` isn't being encoded correctly by your client-side code, meaning that there's another Query String parameter present of `Fuzzy.zip`

Comment: Hi @Rob, Thanks for pointing it out the url looks exactly like what you suspected this is what the url looks like **(servername:port/routeprefix/GetDocumentFromFileStorage/?documentName=Ruzzy&Fuzzy.zip)** Its treating them as two separate parameters

Comment: On a side note, [please don't use `StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), particularly here where it only makes your server slower and adds no benefit at all. The entire `return await...` code can be replaced with `return _documentDownloadService.GetDocumentFromFileStorage(documentName);` and it will do the same exact thing more efficiently.